# How can I sync the build version number with the version number on the executable?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

When building an application using a traditional language, the build version number was embedded as the version in the compiled executable (right-click properties, and there the version would be). It was a magical and beautiful time as this process was automatic, and in sync with whatever the current publish build in your project was. (when i state build in reference to version number, what I actually mean is the entire version string `Major`.`Minor`.`Build`.`Revision` )

Now, Visual Studio still has the same feature, except there doesn't seem to be any way to naturally embed this into the published executable. It does a fine job at using it to name the folder where the build is located, but the exe inside ALWAYS reads v1.0.0.0, even after modifying the `AssemblyInfo` file with the following line :

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")>
```

.. which only sets arbitrary numbers based on the current time for the masked parts, and even still, this isn't what shows as the file version..

When attempting to change the `AssemblyFileVersion` value, from

```
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

to :

```
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")>
```

It is unsupported. Even if it did work, this would NEVER match the build of the project :

[image: publish settings]

How can I embed the above number in an automatic way into the compiled executable so that the version shows up here :

[image: Exe File Properties]

Notice how neither the **file version** or the **product version** reflect neither the `AssemblyVersion` or the version in build settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the 'Release' exe,then you should change the version in:
Project > Properties > Assembly Information

Comment: I assume you mean in a c# project.  As you can see from the `Project` > `Properties` screenshot above, there is no such option.  Second, I want an automatic way to do this. Third, AssemblyVersion != AssemblyFileVersion . In VB.NET this 'property' is located in a file named AssemblyInfo.vb (pretty sure in c# it's the same name, just with .cs instead), and as you can see, I have already been inside that file. Manually increment of build is kind of silly when there is a number that VS increments -- but never uses except for the folder name.

Comment: OK, Try to delete the line:
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>

Comment: That will do.  Still would be nice to have the actual build from the project instead of the random numbers from Microsoft, but.  Result is now  `1.0.5945.4466` where the project auto-increment is `1.0.0.41` .  Since this is the closest I have come to having something sensible instead of all version 1.0.0.0 executable, I am giving this answer to you.  If you could come up with a way to use the auto-increment, that would be fantastic.